# The android:src property of ImageView doesn't support .9.png file?

Tags: android

I need to draw some divider line with some background image. I tried the ImageView control with the image as the value of android:src, but it didn't work. So I replaced the ImageView with a TextView with no text inside and specified the background image as its background. It indeed worked. Is there any better solution besides using a TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `View` Widget?

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fixed_divider_horizontal_bright" >
</View>
```

[image]

NOTE: The dot you see right above this, is a 9-patch image (*used in the code snippet*). ;-)

Comment: This method seems to be more "elegant", except that I have to specify an exact value of android:layout_width or android:layout_height. Thank you!

Comment: @Lion: That is correct. But that is what also makes it flexible. Swapping the values in the width and height will give you a horizontal or vertical divider. :-)

Answer (score 0):

i always just use a View and set the backgound.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your need. If you want use the ImageView as a divider, you can try this attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But a View seems to be enough.